# How to set active class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get link something like this :  `http://local.dev/blog/articles/2/Category12`

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
         <li><a href="/blog/articles/{{$category->id}}/{{$category->slug}}">{{$category->title}} ({{ $category->count }})</a></li>
    @endforeach
```

What i want is to set active class on li for category that im on. Any suggestion? Maybe i need to compare id from url and this in foreach. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ID of a category from URI with `request()->segment(3)`:

```
<li {{ request()->segment(3) == $category->id ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

`yeild()` in the `<li>` section as css class with a name and active it from the view layout. Like

```
<li class="@yield('mymenu')">
    <a href="/blog/articles/{{$category->id}}/{{$category->slug}}">{{$category>title}} ({{ $category->count }})
    </a>
</li>
```

**In the view file**

```
@section('mymenu', 'active')
```

So when you'll click on the link it will generate a class which name `mymenu` and when it will load to a view file then it will be active.